# Why my photos end up half dark?

Tags: motorola-droid, camera, motorola-milestone

Sometimes my motorola milestone camera goes crazy and starts out to take photos half dark.

I noticed that it only happens when flash is on. Also, I've seem this happening when the battery is low (~20%), or the system is slow.

As an example, this is a photo I took minutes ago: http://twitpic.com/2q65bs

Comment: I've never seen that before....  the flash isn't being blocked by anything (like one of your fingers), is it?

Comment: nope, the problem seems to be intermittent; I took a lot of "normal" photos before, then some of them started to be half dark, others totally dark, and some looked normal.

Comment: @OtherMichael done! I didn't notice I was allowed to answer my own question :)

Comment: Sometimes you ask a question you're already researched, and know the answer, and you're putting it in here for the good of humanity. However, I'd leave the question open for a day or two before accepting in those circumstances -- in case a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it is related to low battery, I tried a couple of more tests and if the battery is < 20% this always happens.

Answer (score 2):

Take it back to wherever you bought it and demand a refund.  Regardless if this is a hardware or software problem, you shouldn't have a problem with the sales staff -- show them the picture you linked to.

Comment: I bought it 6 months ago, and it was the first time I saw this problem. I tried again some days after, and it didn't happened.